# Does anyone know of a library that will allow me to share information on different social network services?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sharing

I need to share info using different services like twitter, facebook, and many more, then found the [AddThis Documentation](http://www.addthis.com/help/ios-documentation) and want to know the key advantages of the problems of using them SDK.

Do you recommend me to use a different library?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard a lot of praise for [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/). While I haven't used it myself, it seems simple enough to set up (only 3 lines of code, according to their site) and multiple services are supported.